# Checkbox for a row in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to add, for each row in ListView, a checkbox which will be activated and shown on long press, I don't know whether I think correctly, I should add in row layout a Checkbox which is default hidden and when action start all check box on list will be shown and able to check?
[image: LongPressPic]

Comment: yes you can do this :)

Comment: SO is not a free code writing website.

Comment: Masound I don't want than anyone write code for me, I only wanted to know whether I thought correctly

Comment: IN a ListView, you can inflate custom layouts for each row. SO you simply add a checkbox to the layout, and a textview(if not present). Then you create a master layout, with a checkbox and text at the top, and a ListView underneath. Then you inflate the row view for each listview item. Then when you press the checkbox that checks/unchecks all checkboxes, you loop the items and set them to true or false

Answer (score 0):

**To show `CheckBox` on each row:**

**1.** Add an extra `boolean` variable `isLongPressed` to your adapter class and initialized with default `false` value from adapter `constructor`.

**2.** In your adapter `getView()`/ `onBindViewHolder()` method add an condition like this:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
if(isLongPressed)
{
    checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**3.** Add an method `showCheckbox()` to your `adapter` class to update `ListView` with `checkbox` visible state.

```
public void showCheckbox()
{
    isLongPressed = true;
    notifyDataSetChanged();  // Required for update
}
```

**4.** Call `showCheckbox()` from `onItemLongClick`:

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        your_adapter.showCheckbox();

        return true;
    }
});
```

Here is good tutorial about [Contextual Action Mode](http://www.androhub.com/android-contextual-action-mode-over-toolbar/)

Hope this will help~

Comment: Here is an good example: http://www.androhub.com/android-contextual-action-mode-over-toolbar/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
We will use a recyclerview, and a checkbox adapter

**Chechbox Adapter layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/checkbox_adapter_item_height"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:theme="@style/MyCheckBoxTheme"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="item1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorMaterialBlack"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**A style for checkbox, keep this in style**

```
<style name="MyCheckBoxTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorBlackDimText</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/greenStatus</item>
</style>
```

**A Model for the Checkbox adapter** you can define/add/remove vars in your model

```
public class CheckboxTitlesData {

private String title;
private boolean isSelected;

public CheckboxTitlesData(String title, boolean isSelected) {
    this.title = title;
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    isSelected = selected;
}
```

}

**Checkbox Adapter**

```
public class CheckboxTitleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckboxTitleAdapter.ViewHolder> implements GenericAdapterInterface{

List<CheckboxTitlesData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
private CheckboxTitlesData previousSelection;
protected MyApplication.MenuSelectionListener listener;

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(getRootLayout(), parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

public CheckboxTitleAdapter(MyApplication.MenuSelectionListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CheckboxTitlesData data = dataList.get(position);
    if (data.isSelected()){
        previousSelection = data;
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }else holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    holder.tvItem.setText(data.getTitle());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

@Override
public void changeData(List dataList) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if (dataList == null || dataList.size() <= 0)
        return;
    if (!(dataList.get(0) instanceof CheckboxTitlesData))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Required data type \"CheckboxTitlesData\"");
    this.dataList.clear();
    this.dataList.addAll(dataList);
    (new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, 100);
}

@Override
public int getRootLayout() {
    return R.layout.adapter_title_checkbox;
}

@Override
public void setOnClickListener(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
  holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener((View.OnLongClickListener) holder);
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Bind(R.id.tvItem)
    TextView tvItem;
    @Bind(R.id.checkbox)
    CheckBox checkBox;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        final int pos = dataList.indexOf(previousSelection);
        if (pos == getAdapterPosition())
            return;
        if (listener != null)
            listener.onMenuSelected(dataList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
        CheckboxTitlesData data = dataList.get(getAdapterPosition());
        data.setSelected(true);
        dataList.set(getAdapterPosition(), data);
        if (pos != -1) {
            previousSelection.setSelected(false);
            dataList.set(pos, previousSelection);
        }
        (new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, 100);
        return true
    }
}
```

}

**Interface**, u can remove the interface if you wanted, I just use this for my adapters usually for readability for other dev:

```
public interface GenericAdapterInterface {
  void changeData(List dataList) throws Exception;
  int getRootLayout();
  void setOnClickListener(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder);
}
```

**Recycler view layout xml, add the recyclerview whr you need, this is just an eg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llBody"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_normal"
android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_normal">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity/fragment that uses the recycler view must do this**

```
@Bind(R.id.rvMenu)
RecyclerView rvMenu;

private CheckboxTitleAdapter menuAdapter;
//Define an interface for callback on long press
public interface YourOwnInterface {
    void onLonPress(Object data);
}

private void setUpRecycleView() {
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    rvMenu.setHasFixedSize(false);
    rvMenu.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    rvMenu.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
YourOwnInterface listener = new YourOwnInterface () {
        @Override
        public void onLonPress(Object data) {
            updateView((CheckboxTitlesData) data);
        }
    };
//this interface is needed wen a longpress is made adapter and the callback is given to your Acitivity/Fragment you can perform necessary opreation
    menuAdapter = new CheckboxTitleAdapter(listener);
    rvMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
}

private void updateView(CheckboxTitlesData data) {
   //perform operation on long press
}
```

**Done it works**